# cruzar datos de dos tablas con clases y modelo mvc en php

Tags: php, mvc, poo

necesito de su ayuda, estoy empezando a aprender programacion orienta a objetos y el modelo mvc en php y me surgio un problema, tengo que realizar una lista con sub listas, me explico, tengo las siguientes tablas:
tabla categoria
-id
-nombre_categoria

tabla productos
-id
-id_categoria
-nombre_producto

lo que quiero y no puedo hacer es que me aparezca una lista con todas las categorias de la primera tabla (eso si lo hice), ahora viene el problema, hacer que como sub-nivel aparezcan los productos en la categoria que le corresponda, hasta ahora esto es lo que tengo

la vista:

```
<div class="col-3">
            <h3>Categorias</h3>
            <ul class="list-unstyled pl-3">
                <?php
                    $categoria = controlador::ctrCategoria();
                ?>
                <?php foreach ($categoria as $key => $value): ?>
                <?php $cat = $value["categoria"];?>
                <li class="font-weight-bolder toggle"><a href="index.php?pagina=emprendedor&id=<?php echo $value["id"]; ?>"><?php echo (ucwords($value["categoria"])); ?></a>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

el controlador:

```
<?php
class Controlador{
      static public function ctrCategoria(){

        $tabla = "categoria";
        $respuesta = Modelos::mdlCategoria($tabla);
        return $respuesta;
    }
}
?>
```

y este es el modelo que tengo:

```
class Modelos{
    static public function mdlCategoria($tabla){
        $query = con::cnx()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla");
        $query -> execute();
        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

con esto puedo mostrar los nombres de las categorias, ayuda x favor

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, pon un ejemplo de uso concreto, basado en la realidad de tu aplicación, porque de lo contrario podrías estar perdiéndote en elucubraciones. ¿Qué es lo que quieres exactamente, por qué, para qué y para usarlo dónde? Quizá respondiendo a eso, se podría resolver el problema modelando las clases o de otro modo, todo depende. Yendo más lejos, quizá la relación entre `Producto` y `Categoria`  debería ser expresada en otra entidad, digamos, algo así como `Factura` o `Compra` o `Vendedor` ... no sé si me explico, la POO es 1 concepto amplio en el que el contexto es fundamental

Comment: necesito un menu, donde aparezcan los nombres de las categorias y dentro de cada categoria un submenu con sus productos

Comment: Ok, entonces quizá haya que pensar en una clase llamada `Menu` que una a las tablas `Producto` y `Categoria`. El problema es que cuando hablamos de POO tienes que hilar fino y plantearte ciertas situaciones al momento de diseñar las clases, si no lo haces, podrás invertir días, meses, años, creando un modelo y cuando surja esa situación que no previste se te caerá todo el modelo. Por poner un ejemplo: ¿cómo vas a gestionar en `Menu` la posibilidad de que un `Producto` pueda pertenecer a varias  `Categorias`? ... eso es sólo un ejemplo para entender lo que realmente significa POO realmente.

Comment: eso es lo que quiero, uso el join?
static public function mdlCategoria($tabla, $tabla2){
           <code>
             $query = con::cnx()->prepare("SELECT $tabla.id, $tabla.categoria categoria $tabla2.id_categoria, $tabla2.nombre nombre FROM $tabla JOIN $tabla.id = $tabla2.id_categoria order by categoria");
            $query -> bindParam(":categoria", $categoria, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query -> bindParam(":nombre", $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query -> execute();
            return $query->fetch();
        }
          </code>
con esto no tengo resultado

Comment: Esa es una posibilidad. Podrías por ejemplo traer los datos uniendo ambas tablas y mapeando el resultado usando la clase `Menu` la cual tendría métodos para mostrar los datos. En POO una de las ventajas es que, una vez creado tu modelo puedes usar las clases para llenarlas con información que puede provenir sea de la base de datos, de un JSON, etc.